# How to get the 4. Wednesday of the next Month as DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need a function which gives me the nth DateTime of the next Month. 
For Example: I need the 4th Wednesday of next Month.

My code delivers a wrong Date:

```
private static DateTime FindNextDay(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, DateTime fday, Int32 instance)
{
    DateTime day = new DateTime(fday.Year, fday.Month, 1, fday.Hour, fday.Minute, fday.Second);
    // DateTime day is in this Example= 2014-08.01 11.00 AM   
     if (instance == 2)
     {
         day = day.AddDays(7);
     }
     else if (instance == 3)
     {
         day = day.AddDays(14);
     }
     else if (instance == 4)  //if the 4th week is requested
     {
         day = day.AddDays(28); // i add 28 days
     }
     while (day.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
     {
         day = day.AddDays(1);   // and search the wednesday and return it back
     }
    return day;
}
```

Could you show me a better solution?

Comment: What is your unexpected output?

Comment: Your problem is that you add 28 days to get the 4th Wednesday, but the fourth Wednesday in August 2014 is the 27th

Comment: Yeah, presumably you should be adding `21`, not `28`.

Comment: yes 21 was the right answer . thank you all for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last else if to:

```
else if (instance == 4)  //if the 4th week is requested
    {
        day = day.AddDays(21); // i add 28 days
    }
```

You should add 21 days not 28.

Comment: omg how can i do this, thank you very much. now it shows me the correct day

Answer (score 2):

Something like this..

Get the first day of the next month, keep a count of the number of `wednesdays` you've encountered adding to it when you find one. Return when the count is 4.

```
private static DateTime GetFourthWednesday()
{
    DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);

    int count = 0;
    while (count < 4)
    {
        if (firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 4)
        {
            return firstOfMonth;
        }

        firstOfMonth = firstOfMonth.AddDays(1);

    }

    return firstOfMonth;
}
```

Gives `27/08/2014` if run today

Answer (score 1):

Since because I'm too lazy, I wrote my code like;

```
DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(2014, DateTime.Now.Month + 1, 1);
int count = 0;
    if (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        count = 1;
while (count != 4)
{
    firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(1);
    if (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        count++;
}
Console.WriteLine(firstDayOfNextMonth);
```

Basicly, I check if the first day of next month is `Wednesday` or not, then I iterate my `DateTime` to found 4. Wednesday in next month.

It is working for today and it prints `27.08.2014` which is fourth `Wednesday` of next month.

You can write an extension method like;

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static void FindInstanceNextMonth(DateTime Now, DayOfWeek day, int instance)
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month + 1, 1);
        int count = 0;
        if (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek == day)
            count = 1;
        while (count != instance)
        {
            firstDayOfNextMonth = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays(1);
            if (firstDayOfNextMonth.DayOfWeek == day)
                count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(firstDayOfNextMonth);
    }
}
```

And call it as;

```
DateTimeExtensions.FindInstanceNextMonth(DateTime.Now, 
                                         DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
                                         4);
```